# IE skips a <td>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a query looping and displaying data in a table. However I noticed a an odd behavior in IE. For some reason it skips a `<td>` and make the entire table structure looks weird. This only happens in IE.

in IE,
[image: enter image sdgdsgdhere]

in Chrome,
[image]

<s>Here is my html,</s>,
I meant to say, *Here is my cfm*

```
<TABLE id="WorkOrderList">
  <TBODY>
    <cfloop query="qGetClosed">
    <TR class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></TR>
    <TR>
      <TH id="woNum" class="woNum_cls" rowspan="2"> 
        <a href="WorkOrderAssign.cfm?WONUM=#URLEncodedFormat(trim(qGetClosed.WONUM))#&CanAssign=No">#trim(qGetClosed.WONUM)#</a>
      </TH>
      <TH class="woPriority_cls #pClr#">#trim(qGetClosed.PRIORITY)#</TH> 
      <TH class="woLocation_cls">#trim(qGetReqInfo_MyTables.woLocation)#</TH>
      <TH class="woStatus_cls">#trim(qGetClosed.DELAYDESC)#</TH>    
      <TH class="woRequester_cls">#trim(qGetClosed.UD1)#</TH>
      <TH class="woDate_cls">#DATEFORMAT(qGetClosed.REQUESTDATE,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</TH>
      <TH class="woAssigned_cls">
        <DIV class="woAssigned_Bottom">
          <div class="woAssigned_By">
            <cfif #trim(qGetClosed.ASSIGNEDBY)# NEQ ''>
              #trim(qGetClosed.ASSIGNEDBY)#
            <cfelse>
              <i>n/a</i>
            </cfif>
          </div>
          <div class="woAssigned_Date">
            <cfif IsDefined('qGetClosed.SCHEDSTARTDATE') AND #qGetClosed.SCHEDSTARTDATE# NEQ ''>
              #DateFormat(qGetClosed.SCHEDSTARTDATE, "mm/dd/yyyy")#
            <cfelse>
              n/a
            </cfif>
          </div>
          <div class="woAssigned_To">
            <cfif #trim(qGetClosed.ASSIGNEDTO)# IS ''>
              <i>n/a</i>
            <cfelseif #trim(qGetClosed.ASSIGNEDTO)# IS 'n/a'>
              <i>n/a</i>
            <cfelse>
              #trim(qGetClosed.ASSIGNEDTO)#
            </cfif>
          </div>
        </DIV>
      </TH>
      <TH class="woDate_cls">#DATEFORMAT(qGetClosed.COMPLETIONDATE,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</TH>
      <TH class="woDuration_cls" rowspan="2">#trim(qGetClosed.DURATION)# day(s)</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TH class="woDescription" colspan="7">&nbsp;#trim(qGetClosed.DESCRIPTION)#</TH>   
    </TR>
    </cfloop>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

And here is my css,

```
/*---------Entire List Work Order------*/
.woNum_cls{width:65px; text-transform:uppercase;}
.woReminder_cls{width:80px; text-align:center;}
.woPriority_cls{width:15px;}
.woLocation_cls{width:125px;}
.woStatus_cls{width:125px; left:500em;}
.woRequester_cls{width:100px;}
.woDate_cls{width:100px;}
.woAssigned_cls{width:160px;}
.woDuration_cls{width:78px;}

TABLE#WorkOrderList{
  border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px; border:0px;
  width:975px;
  display:table;
}
TABLE#WorkOrderList THEAD TH{
  color: #000; background-color:#9999FF;
  border: 1px solid black; border-spacing:0px;
  text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:0px 2px 0px 3px;
}
TABLE#WorkOrderList TBODY TH{padding:0px 2px 0px 3px; line-height:none; display:table-cell;}
TABLE#WorkOrderList TBODY TH:not(.woDescription){font-weight:bold;}
TABLE#WorkOrderList TBODY TH:not(.woPriority_cls){background-color:#E6F2F2;}

.woAssigned .woAssigned_Top{text-align:center;}
.woAssigned .woAssigned_Bottom{text-align:left;}

.woAssigned_Bottom .woAssigned_By{width:25px; float:left;}
.woAssigned_Bottom .woAssigned_Date{width:90px; float:left; text-align:center;}
.woAssigned_Bottom .woAssigned_To{width:30px; float:right;}    

TABLE#WorkOrderList TBODY TH{border:1px dotted #006A35;} 
TABLE#WorkOrderList #woNum{border:1px solid blue;}
TABLE#WorkOrderList #woReminder{border:1px solid blue;}
```

This is driving me insane and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try closing all the `<cfelse>` tags.  Also, tags shouldn't be uppercace.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?  Does it validate?

Comment: What does the output html look like? Judging by the screen shots, I'd say you have data being constructed that may be interfering with the html itself.

Comment: Did you examine the HTML code output in IE?  Generally, browsers compensated for incorrect code.  The different browsers implement this error correction differently, hence a possible reason for it to look correct in Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: @Forty-Two Those are [ColdFusion tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_01.html), the `<cfelse>` doesn't actually have a closing tag. However, I agree that the *generated HTML* as seen by the *browser* would give more insight in any possible markup errors.

Comment: Have you tried emitting `<td>&nbsp;</td>` instead of `<td></td>`?

Comment: That looks to me more like something is being inserted in between your Location and Status `<TH>`'s which IE is then encapsulating in an **additional** table cell. Without seeing the actual markup thats being delivered to to IE i dont think i can be of much more help that that im afraid.

Comment: Check your DOCTYPE in IE.  That will sometimes wreak havoc on stuff like this.

Comment: Other people have mentioned that you should be providing the HTML and not the CF code. In the general case: If server side code doesn't produce the rendering you expect in the browser, before asking for help, determine if the server side code is failing to generate the HTML you expect or if the HTML you want is not producing the effect you want.

Comment: Side note: You should be using `encodeForHtml` function for most of those dynamic values, otherwise you're risking HTML/JS injection.

Comment: This is rendered in coldfusion (My apologies it's the a cfm file not a html file).

Comment: @MikeNakis I tried removing that, still no luck.

Comment: @Busches that's what gives the cells background color. I removedand tried but didn't make a difference.

Comment: I appreciate all the pointers but I must reiterate, it's not just that row is having problem all the time. It's a random row, every time.

Comment: @MadushM, I think you're missing the point. You're having a browser issue, not a CF issue, so we need to see what you're sending to the browser to find out why it's rendering badly. Once we know why it's rendering wrong, you can then find the CF that's causing that bad rendering. Random row or not, this is definitely an HTML problem, not a CF problem.

Comment: @DanShort thank you for clarification. So going forward,what do you want me to do now?

Comment: You should post a section of generated HTML that's showing the problem so we can see what might be the cause. @Nicklepedde may very well have the answer for you already, though I've never seem that particular behavior myself.

Comment: understood and you are right @DanShort, Nicklepedde sure have the answer for me. Thank you.

Comment: And thank you and greatly appreciated all the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in IE9 that has a hard time dealing with huge tables, and creates "ghost cells" out of white space between td tags. (Go figure eh?)

The best way to fix is try to remove all white space between the tags. Might make for funky looking markup, but you can cheat by doing something like this:

```
 ...</td><!---//using a CF comment in the white space hides it from the browser, and helps poor IE..
  ---><td>...
```

Comment: Incredibly hard to believe that this kind of flaw exists, but I just ran into the exact same thing, and it was also fixed by removing the space between each `</td>` and the next `<td>`. Must be the dumbest IE bug I've seen all week.

Comment: If the table rows and columns are generated dynamically then it would be very hectic work to remove all white-spaces manually.

Comment: That depends, if it's generated dynamically on the server side, then you have full control over your source, should not be an issue to suppress that white space. If you adding it in dynamically in the client, via JS, then no worries, pretty sure DOM manipulation won't add white space unless you ask.